# ffmpeg produces video I cannot load on latest Safari on iOS

Tags: safari, ffmpeg, mp4

When I encode two videos (mp4 and webm) with these ffmpeg parameters (based on images), I cannot play the mp4 it produces on latest Safari (inside a `<video>` tag) inside my iPhone 6s using the latest iOS too:

```
ffmpeg 
-framerate 15.2 
-f image2 
-thread_queue_size 64 
-i /home/michael-heuberger/abcd/frames/%d.webp 
-y 
-an 
-vcodec libx264 
-vf scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 
-crf 16 
-preset fast 
-profile:v baseline 
-pix_fmt yuv420p 
-movflags +faststart 
/home/michael-heuberger/abcd/videomail_good.mp4 
-vcodec libvpx 
-vf scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2 
-crf 8 
-deadline good 
-cpu-used 1 
-pix_fmt yuv420p 
-movflags +faststart /home/michael-heuberger/abcd/videomail_good.webm
```

I think the above parameters should be solid. I am adding baseline and yuv420p, yet no luck on Safari 9. Why?

And here is the whole ffmpeg output (just ignore the paths to the images/videos):

```
ffmpeg stdout: ffmpeg version 2.7.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.10.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.10.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265 --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from '/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/var/local/tmp/clients/videomail.io/11e5-f576-676eaa40-b0ac-89a86db14ea0/frames/%d.webp':
  Duration: 00:00:00.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: webp, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 400x300, 15.17 fps, 15.20 tbr, 15.20 tbn, 15.20 tbc
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] 264 - core 146 r2555 0c21480 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=15 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=16.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libvpx @ 0xfc5da0] v1.4.0
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/var/local/uploads/videomail.io/videomail/11e5/f5/76/11e5-f576-676eaa40-b0ac-89a86db14ea0/videomail_good.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 400x300, q=-1--1, 15.20 fps, 19456 tbn, 15.20 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
Output #1, webm, to '/home/michael-heuberger/binarykitchen/code/videomail.io/var/local/uploads/videomail.io/videomail/11e5/f5/76/11e5-f576-676eaa40-b0ac-89a86db14ea0/videomail_good.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #1:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 400x300, q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 15.20 fps, 1k tbn, 15.20 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libvpx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (webp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (webp (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0xfc16c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=    9 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lq=0.0 size=      62kB time=00:00:00.59 bitrate= 856.1kbits/s    
video:82kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] frame I:1     Avg QP:15.45  size: 10341
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] frame P:8     Avg QP:15.95  size:  6442
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] mb I  I16..4: 17.1%  0.0% 82.9%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] mb P  I16..4:  6.8%  0.0% 11.3%  P16..4: 36.7% 31.6% 10.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 67.5% 60.4% 43.0% inter: 60.5% 68.4% 5.4%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 29% 21% 18%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 23% 20%  3%  4%  6%  5%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] i8c dc,h,v,p: 60% 21% 14%  5%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] ref P L0: 59.3% 40.7%
[libx264 @ 0xfc2760] kb/s:836.04
```

This makes it difficult for me to play videomails recorded on www.videomail.io on iOS devices.

Am I missing something here? Already did lots of research and tried various combinations, no luck.

If you want to reproduce that, easy: just record a video on www.videomail.io and after that, copy the link of the recorded video page to your iPhone or just download it for local investigation.

Any clues very welcome!

Comment: For image sequences, you should be using `framerate`, not `r`, but in any case, what's with that value? ffmpeg timescale only goes upto, IIRC, a million, so the precision in your rate is wasted. Try two things - assign an integral framerate and prefix a `+` before faststart.

Comment: Please include the complete console output from your command (without `-loglevel warning`).

Comment: thanks mulvya, great input!

Comment: okay @LordNeckbeard, have updated the above problem and added the whole ffmpeg output. hope you can see the cause?

Comment: btw, sometimes i see ffmpeg warning with `ffmpeg stdout: [swscaler @ 0x1318e40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`

Comment: guys, this npm package helped! https://www.npmjs.com/package/iphone-inline-video